# How to use struct vector as an input parameter in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I need to supply a vector of structs to an Rcpp function. The cpp file is as below

```
#include <Rcpp.h>


using namespace Rcpp;

struct teststc{
  int y;
};


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void teststruct(std::vector<teststc>  ys){
  Rcpp::Rcout <<"test"<<std::endl;
}
```

When I compile this cpp file, it returns this error

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'teststc'
```

I actually see some functions using similar input parameters. So, I don't know why mine doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please take a closer look at the Rcpp documentation, starting with [A Brief Introduction to Rcpp](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) and continuing to [Rcpp Extending](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf). In short, the compiler right now has no converter for _your_ struct, let alone a `std::vector<>` around it, so someone has to add this---most likely you.  Else you can use the standard known converters for standard C++ and R types.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for your links. I will read them soon. If possible, can I ask a follow-up question? I actually want to mimic the behaviors of this package (https://github.com/cran/bayesm/blob/master/inst/include/bayesm.h). In the .h file, the author defined a struct, `murooti`. The author also defined a function using the vector of this struct as input ( `mat yden(std::vector<murooti> const& thetaStar, mat const& y);`). Why can he do this while mine doesn't work?  I'm also writing a package. Did I miss something in the package setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to export a function to R that takes as an argument an object of type `std::vector<teststc>`. Such an object does not exist in R, so it cannot pass it to the C++ code.

If you want to be able to pass an object to C++ from R and convert it into your own struct, then you must write the C++ code that will convert an R object to your struct. Rcpp makes this much easier, but it is not magical, and cannot automatically convert an R object into an arbitrary struct without being told how you would like this to happen. You would therefore need to write the C++ code to do this.

For example, the following code will take an integer vector from R, convert it into a `std::vector<teststc>`, then print out the elements of that vector:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace Rcpp;

struct teststc {
  int y;
  teststc(int x) { this->y  = x;}
};

std::vector<teststc> make_testvec(IntegerVector iv) {
  std::vector<teststc> out;
  for(int i = 0; i < iv.size(); ++i) {
    out.push_back(teststc((int) iv[i]));
  }
  return(out);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void teststruct(IntegerVector ys) {
  std::vector<teststc> stc = make_testvec(ys);
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < stc.size(); ++i) {
   Rcout << stc[i].y << ' '; 
  }
  Rcpp::Rcout << std::endl;
}
```

So that back in R I can do:

```r
teststruct(1:5)
#> 1 2 3 4 5
```